# Type/Interface with an enum as a field can't be exported

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript type(or interface) that i use to define my book interface, which i then import from other files.  This works fine until i want to use an enum as one of my field types, the i get a typescript error.

*OK*

```
interface Book {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}

export default Book;
```

I can import the Book type in the rest of my code no problem, but when i change the code to below:

*Not OK*

```
export enum Shelf {
  current,
  finished,
  wishlist
}

interface Book {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  shelf: Shelf;
}

export default Book;
```

With this enum as my shelf property, i get a "'Book' is not defined no-undef" error pointing at the `export default Book` line.  Why can't i use this enum as one of my properties?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine.

I think the error you got comes from a linter, [maybe ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)?
ESLint does not natively support TypeScript. If you use an IDE, the linter may be automatically triggered.